# How can i select a cells row?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to get it done for past week and so far I've reached no where, I want to get the first element of a selected row in *telerik grid view*.

How can I do in multi select mode? Can you please help me with it.

Comment: What about radGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Cell Name"].Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set your grid to only allow a single row selection then the following code will work.

```
yourGridViewName.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value
```

For multiply row selection you'll have to loop through the rows:

```
foreach (var rowInfo in yourGridViewName.SelectedRows)
{
    string firstCell = rowInfo.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But his requirement is for multi select

Comment: it seems that it doesn't know this part (gridviewrowinfo) this is the message error [The type or namespace name 'GridViewRowInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ]

Comment: let me check I'll revert back to you shortly.

Comment: it Deletes just one record,it doesn't support Multiselecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99112/discussion-between-bayeni-and-mostafa-bouzari).